# Cordova/Phonegap iOS - html5 input text type changed after application is sent to background

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

I am totally new in phonegap/cordova development and I have a problem with the keyboard on cordova webview for my app.

What I am trying to achieve is to have an input text with keyboard type that only shows numeric pad (which is type="tel") and also hides the characters that are typed into the input textbox (which is type="password"). What I have tried to achieve this behaviour is by changing the input type twice with javascript. Here's the code for that :

```
<script>
        function changeInputType(){
            document.getElementById("txtPin").setAttribute("type", "tel");
            setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("txtPin").setAttribute("type", "password");}, 750);
        }
</script>

//here is how I use it on the html input 
<input type = "tel" id="txtPin" onlick="changeInputType()" onkeypress="changeInputType()"/>
```

This dirty trick works fine when the user types on the textbox, but when the keyboard is present and I press the home button or do whatever that results to the app being sent to the background, and then I go back to open the app again, the keyboard type will change to the default text keyboard. And the javascript seems to not work anymore when I dismiss the keyboard and then open it up again by clicking on the textbox.

So, if anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong here or has any suggestion on what I can do to fix this problem, please help.

Thank you! cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that to make the keyboard go back to numeric (type="tel") again is to call the javascript method on my AppDelegate through the current visible view controller like so :

```
//get the current visible view controller
UIViewController *viewController = ((UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController).visibleViewController;

if([viewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]])

{
    MyViewController *vc = (MyViewController *)viewController;
    if(vc.webView respondsToSelector:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:)
    {
        //call the javascript function on the webview
        [vc.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"changeInputType"];
    }
}
```